# get branch name from remote repo

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

i try to get branches from remote repo

```
            var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials
            {
                Username = "username",
                Password = "pass"
            };

            string path = @"https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git";
            var repo = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(path, (url, fromUrl, types) => credentials);


            foreach (var reference in repo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reference.TargetIdentifier);
            }
```

if i use `reference.CanonicalName` first is `HEAD` and other is commits

if i use `reference.TargetIdentifier` i have full first name `refs/heads/master` (also i need only last part) and other is commits hashes

how i can get only branch names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `TargetIdentifier`, you should be able to extract the branch name with:

```
string branchName = reference.TargetIdentifier.Replace('refs/heads', '');
```

For all branches, as in [this project](https://github.com/8BtS-P-to-Ab/Translators-SOL/blob/1aeb0a588730bf4b263d059f0258ce2541c67683/Translators/Translators/Translator.cs#L99-L102):

```cs
branches = Repository.ListRemoteReferences("https://github.com/shadow999999/Translators-SOL")
  .Where(elem => elem.IsLocalBranch)
  .Select(elem => elem.CanonicalName
  .Replace("refs/heads/", ""));
```

Comment: Note: that will give you "some-new-feature" even if you call it "feature/some-new-feature" upon creation. Grouping branches like that is quite typical I believe.

Comment: @Xerillio True. Replacing `refs/heads` by '' might be more sensible in this case.

Comment: yes, it helps, but with a `reference.CanonicalName` if I want to get the name of all branches, not just the first one plus the hash

Comment: @hellsmenser I have edited the answer with a list of all branches